# Python2.7 installed setuptools and then install pip always gives an error

Tags: python

I installed python2.7, then downloaded the package for setuptools, installed setuptools for my python2.7 using 'python setup.py install', then I downloaded the zip package and installed pip with 'python setup.py install' But got an error

```
C:\Users\HY>python D:\python\pip-18.1\setup.py install
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\python\pip-18.1\setup.py", line 6, in <module>
     from setuptools import find_packages, setup
 ImportError: No module named setuptools
```

I have easy_install.exe in my python/Scripts directory.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0hhW.jpg)

I hope someone can help me solve this problem. I am reading the book "Python Grey Hat".